# jQuery countdown timer partially hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I'm using this jQuery countdown timer which works well for the most part but I cannot figure out why part of the number that is counting down is partially hidden.

http://techtraininghall.com/home-sound-systems-buying-guide-for-homeowners/

It isn't as smooth as the one in their demo
http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/example/?style=light

I think it has to do with the overflow as it counts down but I can't be sure. Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post an isolated code that does the countdown on jfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the stylesheet of your theme:

```
http://techtraininghall.com/wp-content/themes/minimum/style.css?ver=2.0.1
```

there are `line-height` definition for a set of elements:

```
/* Defaults
------------------------------------------------------------ */

body,
h1,
h2,
h2 a,
h2 a:visited,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Droid Serif', arial, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This restrict the default `line-height:22px`, which is the root cause of your problem.

To fix it, you can modify the custom style in this page:

```
<style id="spp-countd-header-css">
    .dash .digit {margin-top: 40px;} #spp_countd_panel {display: inline-block; height: 1%;}
</style>
```

to:

```
<style id="spp-countd-header-css">
    .dash .digit {margin-top: 12px; line-height: 55pt; } 
    #spp_countd_panel {display: inline-block; height: 1%;}
</style>
```